# What is wrong with this shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

Here is a code I have been working with that will change the current directory and download a file in there

```
$cd mnt/sdcard
wget <a link>
```

But it is somehow this code is not working. It is just giving me a blank next line rather than any outputs.How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd mnt/sdcard
wget "$@"
```

when you call the script `"$@"` in the last line incudes any paramters you add after the name of the script as parameters to the wget.  So the script acts like a **wget** that downloads files into the **mnt/sdcard** directory.

Comment: You should include some explanation of how this is solving the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need to give `wget` a URL to "get."

Comment: The URL section was empty because it was for and example. But I added it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save a file to a specify location, you can use `-O, --output-document=FILE` option of wget to specify the output file. Eg.:

```
wget -O /mnt/sdcard/example.html http://www.stackoverflow.com
```